# Any shell where expansions are turned off without escaping or quoting?

Tags: shell, quoting

Say, with `zsh` one can prefix a command with `noglob` to "turn off filename generation (globbing)".

I'm looking for a shell where similar approach can be used to disable not only globbing but all kind of expansions. Rationale: Using backslash escaping or quotes for any complex command turns it into a bloody mess which is A) difficult to read and comprehend B) unsuitable for re-use on the other levels of nesting.

Comment: Maybe show one of those complex command? I've never seen a shell where escaping and quoting becomes problematic in complex commands. What usually is happening if you mess things up is that you're trying to _inject_ shell variables as code into strings that you evaluate, rather than passing data around as arguments as ordinary.

Comment: If you're regularly doing things where quoting and escaping is a serious problem, then you need to learn a better scripting language, one where such things are not a problem.  shell is a shit language for anything but getting other programs to do any work, and fancier versions of shell like zsh don't actually solve the problem, they only obscure it a little.  Try perl or python. If you're used to writing stuff in sh + sed + awk + tr + all the usual unix tools then perl would probably be best.

Comment: For some problems, writing a program in C is a better solution. Shell is powerful, but it is not a general-purpose language.

Answer (score 3):

In `zsh`, you can do:

```
set -o interactive_comments -o extendedglob
alias '@=:;# '
handle_@() {
  local match
  if [[ $1 = (#b)@\##[[:space:]]##([^[:space:]]##)[[:space:]]#(*) ]] $match
}
preexec_functions+=(handle_@)
```

And then prefix your commands with `@`   (has to make up the whole editing buffer, no `foo; @ cmd` nor `foo | @ cmd`, etc) for the first word after that to be taken as the command name, and the rest of the line to be passed as one single argument to that command:

```
$ @ echo asd'@123 # # qwe $x ``
asd'@123 # # qwe $x ``
```

That means that one argument can't start with whitespace nor contain newline characters though.

That works by aliasing `@` with `:;#`, the `:` noop command (so `preexec` hooks be run) followed by the comment leader, so the rest of the line is parsed as a comment and discarded.

In the `preexec` hook, we split that unprocessed line (in `$1`) into the command and arg. Note the `\##` to allow `#` after `@` in there to work around in bug in older versions of `zsh` (5.3 or older). Note that it won't work in 4.3.12 (from 2011) or older where the comment is not included in `prexec()`'s `$1`.

Of interest, zsh also has the `quote-region` and `quote-line` widgets (bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> respectively by default in emacs mode) which can save the hassle of do proper quoting by yourself.

For, instance, you could do:

```
$ perl -e Ctrl+Space$x = 'whatever';...Alt+"
```

Where <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+@</kbd> (upon which terminals usually send a NUL character), sets the start of the *region*.

Upon <kbd>Alt+"</kbd>, that would be transformed to:

```
perl -e '$x = '\''whatever'\'';...'
```

with the *region* now quoted. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5407916 for how to set the *region* (selection) with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + arrow/motion keys.

Comment: Thank you Stéphane, but that doesn't seem to work on macOS' zsh at least.

Comment: @poige, maybe you have an older version of zsh (see edit)? Does it also not work with `zsh -f`?

Comment: As to quot-region/line — yeah, I'm aware of it, but there's no such a thing as "unquote" so it's one way ticket and finally you end up with the same quoted/escaped mess which I described as not wanted in the original posting.

Comment: @poige, there's `undo` though, and writing an unquote widget wouldn't be so hard using the `Q` parameter expansion flag. You've also yet to show an example of the kind of mess you want to avoid. I've never felt this kind of need in the 25+ years I've been using shells on a daily basis.

Comment: @poige, if that `handle_@` still doesn't work for you (or whoever upvoted your comment above) in `zsh -f`, can you please indicate what you see after entering `functions -t handle_@` and then `@ echo ;#$'`, and which version of `zsh` you're using?

Comment: I am running `zsh 5.8` under Ubuntu, and when I run this exact example, nothing prints out at all.

However, I got a variation of this to work for me. See my "Answer" (for user HippoMan) here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716836/zsh-alias-or-shell-function-to-only-echo-its-command-line-including-shell-cont/716847#716847

Comment: @HippoMan, even after `functions -t handle_@`?

Comment: Also, this doesn't work in the following case: `while SOMETHING; do @ xxx; done`.  This `@` operation only goes into effect when it's the first character of a command which is typed in an interactive shell. Sadly, I believe that the source code for `zsh` would need to be modified in order for this `@` operation to function when applied to any command within any `zsh` construct.

Comment: I just now deleted my penultimate comment which said that this doesn't work for me. It indeed works as described. It's just that I was testing it inside of a `while` loop. I now see what you mean when you wrote that `@` "... has to make up the whole editing buffer ...". I now understand that this caveat applies to constructs such as `for` and `while`, as well.