# zsh: alias or shell function to only echo its command line, including shell control characters

Tags: zsh, alias, function, echo

Using `zsh`, I'd like to create an alias or a shell function that operates as follows:

I want this alias or shell function to echo its command line without honoring any shell control characters such as `<` or `>` or `&` or `$` or `"` or others.

In other words, consider the following example, where I'm using "xxx" as the name of this proposed alias or shell function:

```
xxx ls -Flastr "${something}" >/tmp/xyz &
```

It would simply echo the following as follows, without executing it, including the `>` and `&` and `$` and `{` and `}` and `"`, and without honoring any of those special characters:

```
ls -Flastr "${something}" >/tmp/xyz &
```

I know I can do this by quoting the rest of the command line after the "xxx" and possibly escaping certain characters, but I'm looking for a way to make this occur without any extra quoting or escaping.

Also, I want this to be in effect only for the one, single line which is invoked via this alias or shell function, and not for the entire script.

Is this even possible under `zsh`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that none of the special characters mentioned in the question is available to an alias or function.  The shell acts upon them before invoking the utility.  Could you say more about what the use case is for this?

Comment: I want to use this proposed alias/shell-function to test certain commands. When writing  long, complicated script, I might want to see that certain commands are actually going to be executed when the script is running. For example, if the `ls ...` command that I used an example above appears in a script, I'd like to prefix that command with `xxx` in the script and run the script to see if that code actually is reached, without it being executed. And I want the rest of the script to indeed be executed.

Comment: Also, there is a `preexec` shell function which receives the entire command before special character substitution. However, that `preexec` function cannot change the value of the command to be executed. What I want is something like `preexec` which will also prevent the command from actually being executed

Comment: similar (duplicate?): [Any shell where expansions are turned off without escaping or quoting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/714338)

Comment: Thank you to Stéphane Chazelas. However, the code in the "Answer" to that question doesn't work for me in the `zsh 5.8` under Ubuntu. I used the exact same example that was given in that "Answer", but nothing gets printed at all via that function.

Comment: @HippoMan, works for me with the same version. Can you please reply there to my last comment on my answer?

Comment: I'll reply there soon. In the mean time, I found a variation of that which works for me. I'm post it as an answer here. It will show up in a few minutes after this comment.

Answer (score 0):

A trick to do this is to write an alias that ends with `#` to make the rest of the line a comment, then pull the line from the history. Comments must be enabled with `setopt interactive_comments`. However, it's difficult to know where to start printing. This simple version just prints the whole line.

```
function xxx_function { print -lr -- ${history[$HISTCMD]}; }
alias xxx='xxx_function #'
```

Comment: ... and then someone in a hurry comments out a line that ends with | or \ and then oops

Comment: Thank you for this. But also, $HISTCMD doesn't seem to get set inside of a script.

Comment: @thrig The line can end with `|` or `\\` without any problems. The `#` comments everything until the next newline.

Comment: @HippoMan Well, sure. This wouldn't make any sense in a script. There you can just edit the lines with the right quotes, or use a here document.

Comment: no? worst case is something like "echo this is an example of \" followed by "rm -rf /" and then a quick "xxx echo ..." comments out only the echo line and now rm -rf / is (surprise!) no long a continuation and is run. more likely the script hangs because the continuation line is chewing on stdin that is or is not there and oooooh it was due to the stupid xxx trick

Comment: I already explained in my original question that I do indeed want this to work inside of a script. Also, it needs to work inside of interactive constructs such as "while SOMETHING; do @ xxx; @ yyy; done". That is also considered something non-interactive by zsh, and `set -o interactive_comments` doesn't work in "while" loops and other similar zsh constructs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation on the suggestion by Stéphane Chazelas, and it works for me. I corrected the original "Answer" here based on the comments, below, by Stéphane Chazelas ...

```
set -o interactive_comments -o extendedglob
_donothing() {}
alias '@=_donothing # '
handle_@() {
  [[ "${2}" == _donothing ]] && {
    print -r - "${1}"
  }
  return 0
}
preexec_functions=(handle_@)
```

Comment: Oh! ... not quite. It works if I do this inside of a shell script. But if I put the same code inside of my ~/.zshrc and run a command starting with `@ ...`, it does things like expanding the variables and aliases, and it honors ` &` at the end of the command.

Comment: You're not making use of `interactive_comments` not `extendedglob` here.. Even if you meant `alias '@=_donothing '`,  in `@ whatever > file` the redirection to `file` would still be performed

Comment: Yes, I corrected the `@=_donothing`, above, and the first line of this is indeed using `interactive_comments` and `extendedglob` ... ??? Anyway, as I mentioned, this works from inside of a shell script, but not when I put that code into `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: I mean, you're not using any of the extendedglob operator nor are you commenting out any to prevent it from being run as my answer did.

Comment: Oh, I see. But then how is it working as written inside of a shell script, but not interactively?

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work, only that the redirections (and expansions, and globbing...) are still being performed, as you don't do the commenting out.

Comment: OK. I fixed it now. See the "Answer" above for the changed version. I'm still perplexed as to why my original version DID work from within a shell script and DID NOT work interactively, but this current version works both ways. Thank you again to 
Stéphane Chazelas