# Bash function/script argument copied completely into variable

Tags: bash, variable

How to have Bash function/script argument copied completely into variable as `'` (and may some character else) cannot retain to be in the variable?
e.g.

```
m() {
 v="$@"
 echo "$v"
}

$ m let it be 'foo' bar
let it be foo bar
```

Sincere help is appreciated, thanks before.

Comment: See the stackoverflow question ["How can I preserve quotes in printing a bash script's arguments"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835933/how-can-i-preserve-quotes-in-printing-a-bash-scripts-arguments).

Comment: Note that `v="$@"` _does_ lose some data, but `v=( "$@" )` copies everything it has. `echo` doesn't _preserve_ that information, but that's an echo problem; `v=( "$@" ); echo "${v[*]@Q}"` in bash 5.0 will spit things out as they are; it won't add quotes to `foo` because foo is the same with or without them, but `m let it be 'foo bar' baz` will differ, because `'foo bar'` is different from `foo bar` (one word vs two).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to note here is that when you run e.g.

```
m let it be 'foo bar'
```

the program `m` doesn't get the whole command line, but the shell parses the command line first, processing quotes, variable expansions and stuff like that. The end result that goes to the command is more like an array of separate strings, which in this case would be [`let`, `it`, `be`, `foo bar`].

Similarly, in

```
f="James Matthew"
l="Bond"
m "$l, $f $l"
```

`m` would just see [`Bond, James Matthew Bond`], and would have no idea about the variables and quotes involved.

That means a regular program has no way of getting to the raw input line.

---

There are workarounds for zsh with pre-exec handlers in [Any shell where expansions are turned off without escaping or quoting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714338/any-shell-where-expansions-are-turned-off-without-escaping-or-quoting) and [zsh: alias or shell function to only echo its command line, including shell control characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716836/zsh-alias-or-shell-function-to-only-echo-its-command-line-including-shell-cont), but I can't think I've seen one for Bash.

The nearest you get is the `DEBUG` trap, which sees the command to be executed before expansions, quote processing and redirections. It's not complete though, in that it sees only a single simple command at a time. Comments will get stripped out before it sees them, and an unquoted `;`, `&`, `|`, `&&`, `||`, `(` or `)` (at least) will still be parsed.

Anyway, we could try:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extdebug

handle_@ () {
    local re='[[:space:]]*@ ([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+(.*)'
    if [[ $BASH_COMMAND =~ $re ]]; then
        "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        return 1
    fi
}
m() {
    printf "<%s>\n" "$1"
}

trap handle_@ DEBUG

@ m 'foo bar' doo "$var" > /dev/null
@ m what about this?; date
@ m or some (parentheses)?
```

The script uses the `DEBUG` trap to detect commands that start with `@` , takes the next space-separated "word" as a command to run, and passes the rest as a single argument to it. Returning `1` from the trap handler tells the shell to not actually run the command the normal way, preventing a probable error message and blocking any embedded expansions from running (this requires `extdebug` set.)

The output is something like this, showing that the `date` after the semicolon runs, and that the parenthesis break the syntax:

```
<'foo bar' doo "$var" > /dev/null>
<what about this?>
Sun Sep 18 18:39:38 EEST 2022
debugprint.sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `('
debugprint.sh: line 20: `@ m or some (parentheses)?'
```

To be honest, that's a bit icky, the restrictions with the special characters are rather arbitrary, and I won't guarantee the script doesn't have other issues too.

---

In general, if you're planning this for some sort of production use, I'd suggest reconsidering the structure of the program and taking the string through a file or e.g. a here-doc, depending on what you're doing.

A here-doc makes it relatively easy to feed a raw string in, though it goes through the command's `stdin`:

```
m() {
    m=$(cat) 
    printf "<%s>\n" "$m"
}
m <<'EOF'
Say "$hello" to my 'little friend'
EOF
```

That prints

```
<Say "$hello" to my 'little friend'>
```

With the here-doc delimiter string quoted (in `<<'EOF'`) this lets you put arbitrary text and characters in there without need for worrying about quotes. (Apart from the delimiter string itself, of course, but you can use a randomly-generated one instead of `EOF`.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to convince shell that a single quote is a part of variable value like that:

```
m let it be "'foo'" bar
```

Answer (score 2):

The shell is interpreting the `'` quotes before the function ever sees them, and will do the same with e.g. `"` and `\`. You can escape them though with `\`, e.g.

```
$ m let it be \'foo\' bar
let it be 'foo' bar

and

$ m let it be \"foo\" bar, \' \\ \"$foo\" \"\$foo\"
let it be "foo" bar, ' \ "" "$foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are passing the input unquoted. As a result, the `'` is being consumed by the shell *before* calling your function. The same would happen if you had used a `"`, and it also would fail if you had used globbing characters like `*` or `?`:

```
$ ls
file1  file2

$ m "aa"bb
aabb

$ m f*2
file2
```

The cleanest solution, for me at least, is to always pass your input quoted. This will protect any characters with special meaning from the shell and so ensure that they will be passed unchanged to your function:

```
$ m '"aa"bb'
"aa"bb

$ m "foo 'bar' baz"
foo 'bar' baz

$ m "f*2"
f*2
```