# How to write a function that takes an argument string that does not need to be quoted?

Tags: zsh, alias, function, youtube-dl

I'm writing a function, adding it to ~/.zshrc on my Mac. It's in order to more quickly handle commands to `youtube-dl`.

I have this:

```
function dlv()
{
        cd /Users/admin/Downloads
        youtube-dl -f 'best' "$1"
}
```

But when I make a request I have to input the youtube link with quote marks.

`dlv "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"`

instead of `dlv https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What you ask likely isn't possible because the shell does variable substitution and wildcard glob to the command line before your function sees it.

Comment: Would prefixing the command with `noglob` be enough?  `noglob dlv some-URL-with-shell-globs`.  This would still break if the URL contains `&` though.

Comment: You can't do that with a mere function, as the shell's basic functionality is to process syntax elements, including operators such as `&` and quotes, as well as do globbing before running the function. There might be some hacky workarounds though, they'll be highly shell-specific and perhaps not something one would suggest using "in production". But for zsh, see [Any shell where expansions are turned off without escaping or quoting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/714338/170373) It might be possible to hack something like that up with DEBUG traps in Bash, if necessary.

Comment: @Kusalananda, what's that magic "noglob" command?

Comment: @glenn - it's a [precommand modifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-noglob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `zsh` could [quote the URLs for you](https://github.com/johan/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Zle/url-quote-magic) via functions and `zle` - the line editor:

```
autoload -Uz url-quote-magic
zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
autoload -Uz bracketed-paste-magic
zle -N bracketed-paste bracketed-paste-magic
```

and then when you type or paste a URL in your terminal it'll be automatically quoted.

---

Another way (that also uses `zle`) would be to assign a shortcut e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> to a function that builds up the command line for you, i.e. it inserts the command and its options before the quoted URL:

```
dlv () {
cmd='youtube-dl -f best '
jump=$(( ${#${(qq)BUFFER}} - ${#BUFFER} ))
BUFFER=${cmd}${(qq)BUFFER}
CURSOR+=$(( ${#cmd} + jump ))
}
zle -N dlv
bindkey '^[^y' dlv
```

You use it like this: you type or paste the URL, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> which quotes the URL, adds `youtube-dl -f best`  in front of it and positions the cursor at the end of line. Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
Add the above to your `.zshrc` to make it permanent.

Other people prefer having a widget/plugin that quotes everything after certain commands (see [here](https://superuser.com/a/1513497) or [here](https://github.com/ianthehenry/zsh-autoquoter))... so yes, there are ways to have it quoted for you.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! It works perfectly. Thank you so much.