# Run `git commit -m` with single quotes in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, quoting, git, function

I sometimes use characters such as ! and $ in commit messages, they need to be manually escaped, but not if you use single quotes like this `git commit -m 'My $message here!'`. I tried to write a function to make `gc` and all text following as the message, but no luck in making it use single quotes. Everything I've tried, it still seems to use double-quotes in the end, making the `$message` part hidden, and `!` won't work either.

I've tried this:

```
gc() {
  git commit -m ''$*''
}
```

Also this:

```
gc() {
  message="$*"

  git commit -m ''$message''
}
```

Tried other things too that didn't work, when checking `git log` words starting with `$` are not shown in the message. It works with single quotes, but it's using double anyway.

I want to run `gc My $message here` all text after `gc` should be the message, I can't force it to use single quotes, it ends up double. It would output `My here` only.

Is there a way to write this function so it would work the way I want? Not sure if this is possible, thanks!

If there is you're smarter than Bard, ChatGPT, Claude, and Bing AI, because I asked them all too, for several hours had no luck.

Comment: Please edit your question and show an example of you using your `gc` function. I'm 99% sure the issue is that you are running something like `gc Fixed $var`. If you are, the expansion of `$var` (and `!`) to potentially nothing happens before your func is executed.

Comment: I don't think you can get it any shorter than `gc 'I just fixed $var, yay!'` without messing with shell expansion options.

Comment: @Panki Edited. Yeah I want to force single quotes if possible, that would work too.

Comment: Similar: [Any shell where expansions are turned off without escaping or quoting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/714338)

Comment: See also [How to write a function that takes an argument string that does not need to be quoted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/731845)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL,DR: don't.

What you're asking for is impossible. When you write `gc My $message here`, this is an instruction to expand the value of the variable `message` and use the expansion as part of the arguments of the function.

You can do something like what you want by tricking the shell with an alias that adds a comment marker and calls a function that reads the comment from the shell history. This allows the function to receive arbitrary characters except newlines.

```
setopt interactive_comments
alias gc='gc_function #'
function gc_function {
  emulate -LR zsh
  setopt extended_glob
  local msg=${history[$HISTCMD]#*[[:space:]]##}
  git commit -m "$msg"
}
```

This is not (and cannot be) fully robust. The version I posted requires a space or other blank character after `gc`; if you use a different non-word-constituent character, the commit message might not be what you expect.

**I do not recommend this**. You're making it easy to write a one-line commit message, and hard to write a good commit message. A good commit message explains what the commit does and how. A good commit message is written in an editor. If you write one-line commit messages, you're doing it wrong and you will regret it.

Comment: In summary, it is better to just write `git commit`. If vi/Vim seem too "scary", `EDITOR` can be set to something the user is more familiar with, for example by including `export EDITOR=nano` in a shell startup file (but learning vi/Vim is better as they are more powerful).

Comment: @Vilinkameni There's no reason to use vi to write commit messages unless that's already your favorite editor. Just use whatever editor you use to write code.

Comment: I mentioned vi because it is (usually) the default.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' This worked, thanks! I appreciate the tip, but can't say I agree about one-line commit messages.